# Very slow mysql in C after I mess with /var in Fedora

Tags: mysql, c, fedora

I developed a programme to parse a huge text file and store it into Mysql database using C in Fedora. When I ran this application, it used to consume CPU up to 100% and it was quite fast. 
After I got /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root had no space left, I took the following steps (as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/430862/dev-mapper-volgroup-lv-root-has-no-more-space-left)):

mkdir /home/var
Stop all the services. For example: /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
cp -pr /var/* /home/var
rm -rf /var
ln -s /home/var /var
Start the services again.

After I rebooted my machine, I found all the services didn't work. Fortunately, I made a copy of /var and I could redo all the above steps. My services are all working now. But I found out that when I run my application, it is running very slowly and only uses my CPU up to 10%.

Could you please let me know how I can solve this issue?
Could it be because after I messed with /var I don't have the symbolic link to /var/lock any more?
Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your `/home/` on a network drive, by any chance?

Comment: No. It is all on the local machine.

Comment: Same physical drive for /home and /var?

Comment: Yes Mats. All on  the same physical drive.

Comment: And you have the same type of filesystem on the root and the home LV's?

Comment: Yes, everything is the same.